# Big graphic makes and white lines in previous page (bookdown/Rmarkdown)

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I have added a big PNG (tall, with similar aspect ratio to A4 paper) image in my `rmd` between two paragraphs using the following chunk (caption was made that way since it will include citations):

`````
(ref:cap-etlm) The ETLM.
```{r etlm, results = "asis", echo = FALSE, fig.cap = "(ref:cap-etlm)",  out.width='\\textwidth'}
include_graphics("figures/etlm.png")
````
`````

The problem is, when generating a pdf output, the previous page becomes sparse, with many empty lines (shown with red lines):
[image]

This (could) also be the case if the image didn't take the whole page, but was large enough.

How can I let some of the text (that, in the `rmd`, have been written after the chunk/its reference) appear before the image?

Thanks in advance.

## Edit:

[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/7c99449e57d6e1e03a61a227b1329c06) is `rmd` of a minimal reproducible example (updated screenshot). It also requires `csl` files, etc., which are in a zip file [here on TinyUpload](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00353871109920595102).

Comment: Can you expand your example code, preferably to a [mcve]? Normally fibures created from chunks with a `fig.cap` are placed into a floating `figure` environment which following text to be placed before the figure.

Comment: Hey @RalfStubner, I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file `template.tex` contains the following lines:

```latex
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
```

This forces LaTeX to place figures always HERE, i.e. where they are defined. Removing these two lines solves the problem for me.

Comment: Yeah, that was indeed the issue. Thanks a lot!